# When will this site be closed?

Tags: discussion

With about a question a day, half of them off topic, doesn't seem like the site is viable. When the decision is going to be made?

Comment: It's only been 40 days.  Give it time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without giving specifics, yes there's a decline. However the exact same thing happened with the travel site, in fact it had a worse start (I went hunting through meta comments I posted about it back then a few weeks ago to confirm this).  Then organic results started kicking in and it slowly grew, getting occasional bursts of traffic from articles on lifehacker, reddit, hackernews and more.

It's very early days. We already have more users than travel did at the same time.  It's now a successful graduated SE site.  Expats can be too.

Answer (score 8):

See the blog on '[when a site goes quiet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/)'. We generally don't shut a site down unless one or more things happen:

- Nobody is really using it for *anything* any longer. It's just tripping people up by showing up in search results.
- The community *completely* ceases taking responsibility for its content. Nobody is closing, nobody is editing, nobody is reviewing - it's all falling on the moderators.
- We can't find anyone willing to moderate the site (exacerbated if the bullet above is also true)
- The site loses all relevance. That hasn't happened yet, but if a site grew up around some kind of product, and that product vanished - then everyone stopped using it ... there wouldn't be much point in having a site full of questions about it
- *Extremely* bizarre circumstances where the site begins doing more harm than good with the content it delivers. Also has yet to happen.

As long as people are coming here, asking questions, getting answers in a reasonable amount of time, editing, closing, raising meta discussions, curating tags, etc - we're willing to give a beta as long as it takes.

[Parenting SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting) has been in beta a little over three years, and still receives barely two questions every day. We would not *dream* of closing that site, in fact we're enjoying the challenge of figuring out how we can help boost new questions there.

Many sites are *never* going to be huge, but will serve small communities *better than anything else on the Internet*. That's the goal - be an awesome site for Expats to save hours of their lives searching through horribly broken resources found elsewhere. Keep doing that, and you have nothing to worry about.

I fully expect this site to graduate within 1 - 1.5 years, it's just a matter of getting it exposed in the right places.

Comment: I remember OnStartup was closed, and I don't think any of the bullets you listed was relevant then.

Comment: @littleadv That's bullet #2 - there were about 15 people actively interested in maintaining the site, and hordes of people that drove by with very poor questions, never sticking around afterward. A situation that is _very_ unlikely to happen again.